# Access denied option when i am trying to create table in design mode in sql management studio

Tags: management-studio-express

I am getting the "Access denied" error when i am trying to create a table in design mode in SQL management studio. I tried all the options given into "property" menu of the database, but i was unable to find the appropriate solution for giving the permission for creating a table in design mode.
    So if i need to create a table then i have to write a query for it. Using query i am able to create a database tables.
    So i want a solution so that i can create table using design view as i have to create large number of tables with constraints.
    Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you confirm that the 'Design' view is pointing at the same database you tested with the `CREATE TABLE` script?

Comment: I am clicking on the same database for which i have created a table using query. For all database i am facing the same issue. I tried creating multiple databases